# ng-show on ng-click not working with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, using-directives

I'm trying to display some Edit icons when an Edit Mode link is clicked. So far i've tried ng-click with ng-class and ng-show and it doesn't respond.

Here's my html:

```
<div click-to-edit="questions.n1.name" class="row question"></div>
    <a href="" ng-click="editMode = !editMode">Enter edit mode</a>
```

And the click-to-edit directive:

```
.directive("clickToEdit", function () {
var editorTemplate = '' +
'<div class="click-to-edit">' +
    '<div ng-hide="view.editorEnabled">' +
        '{{value}} ' +
        '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="enableEditor()"></a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div ng-show="view.editorEnabled">' +
        '<input type="text" class="" ng-model="view.editableValue">' +
        '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" href="#" ng-click="save()" ></a>' +
        '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="disableEditor()"></a>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';

return {
restrict: "A",
replace: true,
template: editorTemplate,
scope: {
    value: "=clickToEdit",
},
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.view = {
        editableValue: scope.value,
        editorEnabled: false
    };

    scope.enableEditor = function () {
        scope.view.editorEnabled = true;
        scope.view.editableValue = scope.value;
        setTimeout(function () {
            element.find('input')[0].focus();
            //element.find('input').focus().select(); // w/ jQuery
        });
    };

    scope.disableEditor = function () {
        scope.view.editorEnabled = false;
    };

    scope.save = function () {
        scope.value = scope.view.editableValue;
        scope.disableEditor();
    };

    }
};
})
```

I've also created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aYbtFYvKo3Y4SXAud5mA?p=preview). On script.js, line 11, the ng-show is supposed to be triggered by the ng-click on the html (line 20).

What am I missing? Do I have to be inside the directive clicktoEdit to be able to trigger the ng-show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your directive has isolated scope so `editMode` is not available there. The simplest fix of this issue is to explicitly reference parent scope property:

```
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-show="$parent.editMode" ng-click="enableEditor()"></a>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/8M98LGOfdRrBp5IaaGKZ?p=preview